# Super strange ClassNotFoundException from ObjectInputStream.readObject

Tags: java, serialization

Trying to load a serialized object from ObjectInputStream and getting this mystical error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyClass in
 thread mythread
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
```

The class is in the same classpath as the method that's calling readObject. Everything has a serialVersionUID.

When I do

```
Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass")
```

just before readObject it works just fine.

WTF could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change the class after saving that serialized object? What happens when you serialize, save, and then deserialize in the same method execution?

Comment: "Everything has a serialVersionUID." ...is it the same serialVersionUID? :)